# QWebView shows only static image instead of animation

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

As simple as that

```
  ui->webView->load(url);
```

on that url is some animation. Looks like from CGI, 'cos url is like `http://something/cgi-bin/cgi_1.exe` (this is not working url, mine is in local network now).

But instead of animation my widget shows only static picture. Looks like I'm missing something, but can't find out what.